# Убрать сообщение из файла после конфликта git

Tags: git, github

Произошел конфликт с файлами в github, решил его, но сообщения вида:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
some code..
>>>>>>> 5yhdba557cc2d92fa8a36fd3c51de2576bf3cd50
```

остались, как убрать их?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Следует открыть файл любым редактором и просто удалить ненужные строки.

Возникают в результате мержа, и означают, что файл следует редактировать в ручную, т.к. GIT не справился.